# Returning & Calling on Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, static-methods

I need help calling the printTicket method and passing a call to the method generateSuperLottoNumbers as an argument in the main method. This is for a class so I would just like a little nudge in the right direction and not for anyone to write all the code for me, thank you.

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SuperLottoPlus
{
  public static int[] generateLottoNumbers()
  {
    int[] lotto = new int[6];
    Random nums = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < lotto.length - 1; i++)
    {
      lotto[i] = nums.nextInt(47) + 1;
    }
    lotto[5] = nums.nextInt(27) + 1;
    return lotto;
  }

  public static int[] printTicket(int[] arr)
  {
    int[] lotto = generateLottoNumbers();
    try
    {
      PrintWriter write = new PrintWriter("lotto.txt");
      write.println(lotto[0] + " " + lotto[1] + " " + lotto[2] + " " + lotto[3]
          + " " + lotto[4] + " " + "(MEGA: " + lotto[5] + ")");
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException a)
    {
      a.printStackTrace();
    }
    return printTicket(arr);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    System.out.println("How many lottery tickets would you like?");
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String tickets = keyboard.nextLine();
    int[] lotto = printTicket(null);
  }
}
```

Comment: I see no `generateSuperLottoNumbers` method, and it's perplexing why you're passing `null` to `printTicket` in `main`.

Comment: i see some infinity `return printTicket(arr);` mean SO